# Validate checked checkbox quantity

Tags: yii2

I have a voting form and I would like to validate the minimum and maximum number of candidates that each voter can vote for. These max and min values are stored in the logged user's session. What better way to do it?

**MODEL Voto.php**

```
public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'voto';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['eleicao_id', 'candidato_id', 'cargo_id', 'urna_id', 'created'], 'required','message'=> 'Selecione no mínimo 1 candidato!'],
            [['eleicao_id', 'cargo_id', 'urna_id'], 'integer'],
            [['created','candidato_id'], 'safe'],
            [['eleitor_hash'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
```

**FORM _form_votacao.php**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php
    $candidato = ArrayHelper::map(candidato::find()
                    ->where(['status' => 1])
                    ->Andwhere(['eleicao_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->eleicao_id])
                    ->orderBy("nome ASC")
                    ->all(), 'id', 'nome'
                );

    echo $form->field($model, 'candidato_id')->checkboxList($candidato, [
        'class'         => 'h4',
        'data-toggle'   => 'button',
        'item'          => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return "<label class='col-md-5'><input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='{$name}' value='{$value}'> {$label}</label>";
        }])->label(false);
    ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Confirmar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Note: This list of candidates is dynamic, loads the candidates according to the parameters of the user logged in.

Rules Test **UPDATE**:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['candidato_id', 'validateCandidates','message'=> 'teste'],
        ];
    }

    public function validateCandidates($attribute, $params, $validator){
        if(count($this->candidato_id) >= 4){ // test with value 4
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Error message');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create custom validation rule: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#inline-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom validation. Something like this:

**Model Voto.php**

```
    public function rules()
        {
            return [
            ....
            ['candidato_id', 'validateCandidates'],
            ....   
            ];
        }

    public function validateCandidates($attribute, $params, $validator){
        if(count($this->candidato_id) < {session_min} and count($this->candidato_id) > {session_max}){
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Error message');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was unable to get the number of items in the array

Comment: I did as you said but you are not performing the validation. Form is submitted normally

Comment: hehe, I needed to insert $ model-> validate () in the controller